# rhomobile how can i create android keystore with new credentials on linux

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails-3, rhomobile, rhodes

I built a rhomobile android app for production and during the process i provided the credentials(name, company, city, etc) which generated a keystore.

Now i want to build with new credentials and while doing so it is not asking me for the credentials again and by default taking the previous credentials provided by me in the first built.I am using a linux system.

Any solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a new **keystore**.

1. Go to **home directory** (for linux systems).
2. Use **Ctrl + h** to view the hidden folders.
3. You will find a **.Rhomobile** folder.
4. Under this folder you will find a **Keystore**.
5. **Delete** this **keystore** and build your app again using **rake device:android:production**. During the build you will be asked for
   new credentials. You are ready to go.

Answer (score 0):

You've to create your own production signature file inside a keystone, this process is described on [Android developer website](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html).
Once you've your keystore you can add it to your build.yml as described in [Rhodes documentation](http://docs.rhomobile.com/en/4.1.0/guide/build_android#building-an-android-production-version).

Once you've your keystore file you can backup it and use on other machines if you need to certify a new APK.